# The multi-part identifier "alias.field" could not be bound

Tags: sql

Hi i keep getting the error "The multi-part identifier "Users.USERS_ID" could not be bound" i am unsure of what is wrong with the query.

This is what my query looks like;

```
SELECT Events.*, Users.UserName,Users.USERS_ID, 
Users.ThumbnailPic,
Users.CountryName,
ISNULL(UserStatusUpdates.UserStatus,'No Updates')AS LastUpdate,
UserStatusUpdates.MediaTypeID,UserStatusUpdates.USERSTATUS_ID,(UserStatusUpdates.AddDate)

FROM Events
JOIN Users ON Events.UserID = Users.USERS_ID
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 UserStatusUpdates.UserStatus,UserStatusUpdates.MediaTypeID,
UserStatusUpdates.USERSTATUS_ID,UserStatusUpdates.AddDate, UserStatusUpdates.UserID
  FROM UserStatusUpdates  where UserStatusUpdates.UserID = Users.USERS_ID
ORDER BY AddDate DESC) AS UserStatusUpdates ON UserStatusUpdates.UserID = Events.UserID 

WHERE Events.EventID = @EventID 
AND Users.bDeleted = 'False' 
AND Users.bSuspended =  'False'
END
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong

Comment: The Users table does have a column named USERS_ID (not USER_ID)?

Comment: especially, there are some UserID columns and one USERS_ID?

Comment: Yes the primary key in the Users table is called USERS_ID. And the foreign key in the Events table is called UserID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is in this bit:

```
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 UserStatusUpdates.UserStatus,UserStatusUpdates.MediaTypeID,
UserStatusUpdates.USERSTATUS_ID,UserStatusUpdates.AddDate, UserStatusUpdates.UserID
  FROM UserStatusUpdates  where UserStatusUpdates.UserID = Users.USERS_ID
ORDER BY AddDate DESC) AS UserStatusUpdates ON UserStatusUpdates.UserID = Events.UserID
```

The SELECT TOP 1 clause does not have access to Users.USERS_ID.

I don't see where you are using any of the data returned from UserStatusUpdates. So I'm assuming you are using that bit to filter out rows where that join produces nothing. In that case, you may be able to move that out of a join, and into the where with an EXISTS. But it's a left join, so even my assumption doesn't really apply.

I think the solution is described in the question and answer
[Top 1 with a left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033699/top-1-with-a-left-join)

Comment: I've edited to add a suggestion that may work. I'd need to know more about what you're trying to accomplish instead of having to guess to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry i removed the userupdates part in order to shorten the code, i am using it.

Comment: see the end of my answer, I've added a link to what I think will solve your problem

Comment: Hi Hatchet, i tried that it worked, however it did not give me items where a user does not have an item within the UserStatusUpdates Table.

Comment: you might want to post a different question with your current code, or add a comment to this showing what you replaced the TOP 1 with.